# Could you tell me what these "it" mean?

Tags: pronouns

The interviewer:

> “Black Panther” gave us a utopia that we do not necessarily have in real life. What excited you the most about the sisterhood you had as actresses or the female solidarity that your characters had for each other in “Wakanda Forever”?

The interviewee:

> The undervaluing of women because of their gender doesn’t exist in Wakanda. We saw that in the first film, which is why it resonated. This new film continues with the conceit that this is a world where those things don’t exist. But the question we’re tackling is not their womanhood. It’s their beliefs, passions, loves and arguments, and ***it*** creates a robust drama. Hopefully, the world as we know it watches and is empowered by ***it***, despite ***itself***.

1. What does these bold "it" refer to?
2. What "despite itself" mean?

Comment: The referent for **it** is perhaps a little vague, but basically it's the aforementioned *questioning / exploring of women's beliefs, passions, loves and arguments* - a fruitful subject area within which the Marvel Cinematic Universe writers can create robust dramas.

Comment: ...I have no idea what the writer means by ***despite itself***. That particular turn of phrase usually implies doing something reluctantly or shamefacedly, but why the writer should imply that "the world" is ashamed of watching MCU movies is a mystery to me.

Comment: I'm sorry. I updated the original question. Maybe it is now clear to answer.

Comment: I think the _itself_ has a different referent from _it_: _Itself_ refers to the world, and _despite itself_ means something like "despite all the things the world does to try and avoid talking matters of this sort".

Comment: I agree with @ColinFine and would refer to the phrase "the world as we know it" meaning the real world (not the fictional world of the drama) and then "itself" refers again to the real world. Thus, for me, the final sentence is inviting us (in the real world) to watch the drama and learn from it, despite the failings and problems of our real world.